# VBA Word Copy table's value without referencing the table's sequence number

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word file where is changing number of tables. I need to copy the value from the 3rd or 4th table (it always changes).

The table has always 1 row and 2 columns (other tables are completely different), first column has always the text "Temperature", text in the second column is changing and I need to copy that text.

If it helps, there is always word "Specifications" before the table starts.

---

Before I realized that number of tables is not permanent, I used that code. (In case if it could be helpful)

So, can you please advice how to automate the process?

```
Sub Demo()
Dim wsCopy as Word.Document
Dim wsDest as Worksheet

    Set wsCopy = Documents(1)
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With wsCopy.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "Temperature"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
      With .Cells(1)
        If .ColumnIndex = 2 Then
          Set Rng = .Range
          Rng.End = Rng.End - 1
          Rng.Copy
          Exit Do
        End If
      End With
    End If
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    wsDest.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "N").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: You have described a good set of rules for identifying the table you need.  So now write a function that scans each table in a document in turn until it finds the one that meets your rules, then return that table range from the function so you can do the necessary further processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "Specifications"
    .Execute
    If .Found = False Then Exit Sub
  End With
  .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  .Find.Text = "Temperature"
  Do While .Find.Execute
    If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
      If .Cells(1).ColumnIndex = 1
        wsDest.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "N").Value = _
          Split(.Tables(1).Range.Cells(2).Range.Text,vbCr)(0)
        Exit Do
      End If
    End If
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, but the proposed solution does not work. I tried everything what I can but still not working. It just copies nothing and I do not know what is the problem.
Can be problem in that I am copying value form Word and then trying to paste it in Excel?

Comment: Also modified the code with your solution to make clear how it actually looks now

Comment: Code revised. Try it now. «Also modified the code with your solution to make clear how it actually looks now» You probably shouldn't have done that, since it's no longer clear what you were working with.